# Nested callback function in C

Tags: c, callback, nested-function, funcall

I have written some code for calling nested functions using callback.
But i am not getting output as I expected.

Please have look into code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int (*f_ptr)(int a, int b);
typedef int (*pair_ptr)(f_ptr);

pair_ptr cons(int a, int b)
{

    int pair(f_ptr f)
    {
        return (f)(a, b);
    }
    return pair;
}

int car(pair_ptr fun)
{
    int f(int a, int b)
    {
        return a;
    }
    return fun(f);
}

int main()
{
    int a = 3;
    int b = 4;
    // It should print value of 'a'
    printf("%d", car(cons(a, b)));     // Error : It is printing '0'
    return 0;
}
```

**I have also tried with function pointer but in that also i am getting the same output as above.**

Comment: `pair` tries to use `a` and `b` which no longer exist. They're not captured, are they?

Comment: C has no concept of *closures*, or facilities for using them. You need to "fix" `a` and `b` some other way

Comment: Please don't tag questions about C as C++. They are not the same language. (In C++ this would be trivially handled using a lambda or a functor, neither of which are solutions that work in C.)

Comment: in general, the C language does not allow nested functions (although `gcc` does have such an extension)`  Strongly suggest elimination of the 'nesting' of the functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (maybe move functions and variables related to the *closure* to their own file):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (*f_ptr)(int a, int b);
typedef int (*pair_ptr)(f_ptr);

static int PairA, PairB;
static void setPairA(int a) { PairA = a; }
static void setPairB(int b) { PairB = b; }

int f(int a, int b) {
    (void)b; // removed unused parameter warning
    return a;
}

int pair(f_ptr fp) {
    return fp(PairA, PairB);
}

pair_ptr cons(int a, int b) {
    setPairA(a);
    setPairB(b);
    return pair;
}

int car(pair_ptr fun) {
    return fun(f);
}

int main(void) {
    int a = 3;
    int b = 4;
    printf("%d\n", car(cons(a, b)));
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `pair()` is not reentrant, nor can you call it with different values for `PairA` and/or `PairB` at the same time.

Comment: Your anwer is worked fine. Thanks for your support.

I have use global variable concept from your code into my original code, and it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

C doesn't support nested function, but a GCC extension does. The [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) say:

> If you try to call the nested function through its address after the containing function exits, all hell breaks loose.

`pair` tries to use `a` and `b` which no longer exist. GCC might provide nested functions, but they don't provide [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)). This means the values of `a` and `b` aren't captured by the function; it's merely an address being returned by `cons`.